# MySQL Error 1064 creation of the table works but not inserting data

Tags: mysql

I need to import a prestashop project into my local server which use MySQL 8.0.22

I have the SQL Export :

```
CREATE TABLE `ps_product_shop_2016-06-17` (
  `id_product` int unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

the creation of the table works but when it comes to **insert data** like this :

```
INSERT INTO ps_product_shop_2016-06-17 VALUES ('1');
```

here is the error I get :

```
INSERT INTO ps_product_shop_2016-06-17 VALUES ('1') Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-06-17 VALUES ('1')' at line 1 0,00048 sec
```

is there a way to allow into my sql server the character `-` ?

Comment: This looks like the beginning of a Database design error. A table for a day is a bad idea. Instead have a table in which there is a date column

Answer (score 0):

You have a char `-` (minus) in table name this is not allowed for plain tablename. In order to use this symbol you have to wrap the whole table name in backtics everywhere you use this table name.

```
INSERT INTO `ps_product_shop_2016-06-17` VALUES (1)
```

and (as suggestion) you should not use number inside quote ..